# SKAction Animations not working on SKSpriteNode

Tags: ios, swift3, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skaction

I have some code that animates a start screen, however, on running, the start screen doesn't do anything at all. Here is my code:

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

let fadeOut = SKAction.fadeOut(withDuration:2)
let fadeIn = SKAction.fadeIn(withDuration: 2)

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    let startScreen = SKSpriteNode()
    startScreen.self.childNode(withName: "startScreen")

    startScreen.run(fadeOut) {
        startScreen.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed:"pong")
    }

    startScreen.run(fadeIn)

    startScreen.run(fadeOut) {
        startScreen.alpha = 0.0
        startScreen.zPosition = -2
    }

}
}
```

Comment: You are running fadeOut and fadeIn at the same time, nothing is going to happen (except fade out running twice as fast maybe?)

Comment: I tried to run just let fadeOut and the first SKAction still didn't work

Comment: `startScreen.self.childNode(withName: "startScreen")` I do not know what this is,  I assume `startScreen.self` needs to be deleted

Comment: See my other comment in your other question with not doing `let startScreen = SKSpriteNode()`

Comment: oh you have a `.` where it should be `=`, yeah just do  `let startScreen = childNode(withName: "startScreen")`.  Get out of the habit of using `self` unless you absolutely have to use it for dis-ambiguity or for blocks/closures.

Comment: removing `self`. reveals a fatal error. How ever I did simplify code like this: `let startScreen = self.childNode(withName: "startScreen") as! SKSpriteNode`

Comment: removing self should not get you a fatal error, I do not know what you are doing, but self should be implied.

Comment: Rerunning, the first fade out, worked